# Loopback does not discover Oracle relations

Tags: node.js, oracle, loopbackjs

Following
[Loobback Docs: Discovering models from relational databases](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Discovering-models-from-relational-databases.html), [Stackoverflow answer: Loopback not discovering models](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31312012/3263848) and [Loopback datasource juggler API: Datasource](http://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback-datasource-juggler/#datasource-prototype-discoverschemas) I created a discover js script to get models from an oracle database. The problem is that it never managed to read the relations from the tables. I used the methods

- discoverAndBuildModels - The result object had the properties of the table and an array called relations but that array was empty
- discoverSchema - I managed to get the actual model JSON file and write it to the appropriate location. As the method is described in the api to not read relations i was not surprised to not find any here
- discoverSchemas - Includes option to read relations (called relations but also tried it with associations) which gave me a similar result than discoverSchema but the "relations" tag only had an empty json object assigned to it.

I tried all options with a variety of relations and associations settings but none of them gave me anything but an empty object as the "relations" tag.

Am I missing something in the setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh boy, we've also had this issue. You just have to make sure that your user has the appropriated rights. Choose a privileged user (maybe admin?) to gather the data and it should work.

Check out this question for reference: [How to query the permissions on an Oracle directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390388/how-to-query-the-permissions-on-an-oracle-directory#6390518)

Comment: Thank you so much. Like you said i tried to discover the Models using an admin user just to make sure and voila... it got the relations perfectly. Not sure what permission was missing exactly as the user i tried it with had basic Select, Update,Delete, Insert rights but using your link i'll probably find out. Nevertheless it's working now so that's a good start :)

Comment: @MariusR I'm in the database development industry since 45 years now. I've seen it all.